# How to interpret a significant coefficient of 0?

Tags: regression, interpretation, regression-coefficients

I just ran a multiple regression with 8 predictor variables. Two of them have a significant coefficient, which is 0.000.

How can I interpret this? I find it strange that an effect which basically is an effect of 0 turns out to be significant...

Thanks!

Comment: The average height of African lions at the shoulder is 0.000 miles, but strangely that is significantly greater than zero.

Comment: `> round(4/5280,3)` $\\$
`[1] 0.001` (perhaps overly pedantic, but servals would be better than lions)

Answer (score 2):

Is it basically zero or is it multiplied with large values in the tens of thousands? How many datasets were used? If many, then small effects become highly signifikant. In the end it burns down to the question of how large the coefficient and how large it's standard error is.

Comment: Yes, the dataset is pretty large. It has approx. 65000 cases... The standard errors are also 0.000.

Comment: Can you convince your Statistic Software to print more digits? This is no good standard. You need to see all relevant digits, not just the first four!

Comment: Yes, for one the coefficient is 1.17e-06 with a standard error of 3.92e-08. 
The other one has a coefficient of 3.15e-06 with a standard error of 1.01e-07.

Comment: The initial question was, how to interpret this. The word 'significant' has a different meaning in statistics than in everyday English. With n=65000 the slightest imaginable effect becomes statistically significant, no matter how irrelevant it may be. The statistical finding is probably sound, still it may be irrelevant if you consider the coefficient to small.

Comment: Can you rescale the variables in some more meaningful way? For instance, thousands or millions of dollars instead of dollars, etc.

Comment: I agree with some of the above comments about rescaling (normalizing/standardizing) and see if your results differ and become more interpretable to you then.